# cellForItemAt not called if numberOfItemsInSection is 1 UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, cell, uicollectionviewcell

Following is my code which is **working fine if numberOfItemsInSection is greater than 1** but **if numberOfItemsInSection is equal to 1 it should display single cell but it is not happening**, for numberOfItemsInSection equals 1 noting is displayed and cellForItemAt is not called

Also initial numberOfItemsInSection is Zero after making api call and receiving data it becomes one and I call following code as well

```
tabsCollectionView.reloadData()
```

Other code

```
    tabsCollectionView.delegate = self
    tabsCollectionView.dataSource = self




func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return menuResult?.foodMenuItems?.count ?? 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = tabsCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "foodTabsCollectionViewCellID", for: indexPath) as! FoodTabsCollectionViewCell
    cell.foodMenuItem = menuResult?.foodMenuItems?[indexPath.row]
    cell.setUI()
    return cell
}


func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1

}
```

**following code related sizing in side viewDidLoad()**

```
 if let flowLayout = tabsCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 70)
        flowLayout.itemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
        tabsCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = flowLayout
    }
```

**sizeForItemAt method**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    var height = collectionView.frame.height
    var width  = collectionView.frame.width
    if let flowLayout  = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        width = flowLayout.estimatedItemSize.width
        height = flowLayout.estimatedItemSize.height
    }

    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
}
```

**Following is code inside FoodTabsCollectionViewCell**

```
 override func preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
    setNeedsLayout()
    layoutIfNeeded()
    let size = contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(layoutAttributes.size)
    var frame = layoutAttributes.frame
    frame.size.width = ceil(size.width)
    frame.size.height = ceil(size.height)
    layoutAttributes.frame = frame
    layoutIfNeeded()
    return layoutAttributes
}
```

Comment: what is the returned value of `menuResult?.foodMenuItems?.count ?? 0` ?

Comment: value returned in 1

Comment: There is too much code to follow I could provide you with playground code to make a basic collection view work with 1 cell and 1 section, if you need.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I tried to set a flexible width to a cell containing a UILabel with variable width (actually the size was related to the width of the text of the UILabel)

So initially I was using this approach (THIS was causing the problems):

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
layout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize <--- THIS
layout.itemSize.height = 70 <-- THIS
```

Then I removed the automaticSize (and itemSize.height) as below:

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
```

And it worked.

To make sure that I had flexible cell width I used this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    
    let dummyCell = MyCell(frame: .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: 40))
    
    
    dummyCell.name = users[indexPath.item].name
    
    // 3. Force the view to update its layout
    dummyCell.layoutIfNeeded()
    
    // 4. Calculate the estimated size
    let estimatedSize = dummyCell.systemLayoutSizeFitting(.init(width: frame.width, height: 40))
    
    return CGSize(width: estimatedSize.width, height: 40)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem will happen when the collectionView scroll direction is horizontal and the height of collectionView is less than 50. I had the same problem and I increased the collectionView height to 50 then the problem solved.